# How to access index column of pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to access the Date/index column of a pandas pivot table, then use the date as matplotlib axis to plot stock data in an object oriented manner, I am trying figure out how I might get the date into its own object?  Thank You

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
amazon = yf.download('amzn','2000-01-01','2019-09-26')
amazon.head()

            Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2000-01-03  81.50   89.56   79.05   89.38   89.38   16117600
2000-01-04  85.38   91.50   81.75   81.94   81.94   17487400
2000-01-05  70.50   75.12   68.00   69.75   69.75   38457400
2000-01-06  71.31   72.69   64.00   65.56   65.56   18752000
2000-01-07  67.00   70.50   66.19   69.56   69.56   10505400
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `amazon.index`:

```
print (amazon.index)
DatetimeIndex(['1999-12-31', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05',
               '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07', '2000-01-10', '2000-01-11',
               '2000-01-12', '2000-01-13',
               ...
               '2019-09-12', '2019-09-13', '2019-09-16', '2019-09-17',
               '2019-09-18', '2019-09-19', '2019-09-20', '2019-09-23',
               '2019-09-24', '2019-09-25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=4965, freq=None)
```

But if plot in pandas, e.g. by [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) not necessary:

```
amazon['Open'].plot()
```